# What rights does a client have in Japan to protect their privacy from being leaked by their lawyer?

Tags: attorney-client-privilege, confidentiality, japan

I know attorney-client privilege isn't really a legal principle in Japan, yet, but without it how do Japanese clients protect their privacy/confidentiality?

Recently I watched some Japanese legal dramas, and it is a really common occurrence that a (defense) lawyer finds out about some secret wrongdoing of their client and goes to the opposing party, for example, the prosecution, and tells them about it, in an attempt to "do the right thing", and for the sake of "justice". In those TV series/movies, a lawyer would go as far as spend a ton of time digging into their client's dirty past in order to "find the truth." Such plots are so common that they have become a trope on Japanese TV. From a U.S. perspective, these plots seem complete bananas. And yeah, yeah, I know TV dramas are largely fictional and unrealistic. I am well aware of that. But seeing how some of my Japanese friends seem to find those plots totally believable, and after reading show reviews on Japanese blogs, it's become clear that a lot of Japanese people actually believe in and applaud such "justice-serving/truth-seeking behavior." It almost seems like part of the Japanese ethos.

This is 100% inconceivable in the U.S. where such behavior would instantly constitute a breach of attorney-client privilege/confidentiality, so the dramas piqued my curiosity and prompted me to do some research. I understand that attorney-client privilege wasn't and still isn't a concept (see for example [this piece](https://www.relativity.com/blog/the-attorney-client-privilege-japan-and-americas/)) in Japan and it was only in recent years that [the idea was proposed in Japan](https://www.mofo.com/resources/insights/200414-japan-ftc-attorney-client-privilege.html). So how does a client legally protect their privacy in Japan and prevent something like the drama plots from happening?

Comment: It might interest you to know that Japanese conviction rates are over 99% compared to 75-85% for US jurisdictions